# Google Places API concatenate search string with MySQL response

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to create a Google Places URL that can be reused and concatenated with a response from my database.. Not getting this to work and have been trying for a couple of days with no luck! If I echo out the both strings, from PHP on to my web page and copy&paste it, both addresses generate the same Google Places result, but when I print the JSON decoded response I get UNKNOW_ERROR from Google..

This is what I have been trying to use. The first and the second $googlePlacesAPI contains the exact same URL, just that one is concatenated and the other is "hard coded".

```
$googlePlacesAPI =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . 
$BarName. "+" . $BarCity . "&sensor=false&types=bar|night_club&key=" . $mySuperSecretKey;

$googlePlacesAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" . 
$BarName. "+" ."Göteborg". "&sensor=false&types=bar|night_club&key=" . $mySuperSecretKey;
```

To get the value of $BarCity I use this piece of code (before creating the $googlePlacesAPI variable):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = $CityID"));
mysqli_close($con);

$BarCity = $row['CityName'];
```

EDIT:
This is how I decode the answer:

```
$placesSearch = json_decode(file_get_contents($googlePlacesAPI));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to close the connection after you're done with $row:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = $CityID"));
$BarCity = $row['CityName'];
mysqli_close($con);
```

See a sample of mysqli_fetch_array usage at https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array#example-1728

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried this, I also read the samples you posted, but sadly it didn't help me.. Really frustrating problem!